# помогите с закладкой в listview

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как сделать закладку в listview как в проект https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=ru

Может есть готовая реализация где нить?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что имеется ввиду под "Закладкой"? На какой из скринов программы она видна?

Comment: На 4-ой.....звездочка....просто нажимаешь ее и она типа так сказать подсказывает этим что урок важен для пользователя

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реализации собственных видов строк ListView придется создавать свой адаптер с переопределенным методом getView, и в него подпихивать такой вид строк, который нарисуете сами. Хороший пример например [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/), или просто сами поищите по запросу "custom listview android"